# How can I generate all possible LINQ strings of a json object for Json.net?

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net

In json.net we can using linq to json based on [this tutorial](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).

I want to know is there any way to generate a string query or not? Consider this json example:

```
{
  "Name": "Test",
  "Status": [
    "S1",
    "S2",
    "S3",
    "S4"
  ],
  "People": [
    {
      "Name": "A",
      "Family": "AA",
      "Addresses": [
        {
          "Country": "A2",
          "City": "A1",
          "Phones": [
            "A3",
            "A4",
            "A5"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "B",
      "Family": "BB",
      "Addresses": [
        {
          "Country": "B2",
          "City": "B1",
          "Phones": [
            "B3",
            "B4",
            "B5"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "C",
      "Family": "CC",
      "Addresses": [
        {
          "Country": "C2",
          "City": "C1",
          "Phones": [
            "C3",
            "C4",
            "C5"
          ]
        },
        {
          "Country": "C7",
          "City": "C6",
          "Phones": [
            "C8",
            "C9",
            "C10"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I wrote all possible LINQ strings by hand:

```
// JSON.NET Linq Strings (by HAND)

"Name"
"Status[0]"
"Status[1]"
"Status[2]"
"Status[3]"
"People[0].Name"
"People[0].Family"
"People[0].Addresses[0].City"
"People[0].Addresses[0].Country"
"People[0].Addresses[0].Phones[0]"
"People[0].Addresses[0].Phones[1]"
"People[0].Addresses[0].Phones[2]"
"People[1].Name"
"People[1].Family"
"People[1].Addresses[0].City"
"People[1].Addresses[0].Country"
"People[1].Addresses[0].Phones[0]"
"People[1].Addresses[0].Phones[1]"
"People[1].Addresses[0].Phones[2]"
"People[2].Name"
"People[2].Family"
"People[2].Addresses[0].City"
"People[2].Addresses[0].Country"
"People[2].Addresses[0].Phones[0]"
"People[2].Addresses[0].Phones[1]"
"People[2].Addresses[0].Phones[2]"
"People[2].Addresses[1].City"
"People[2].Addresses[1].Country"
"People[2].Addresses[1].Phones[0]"
"People[2].Addresses[1].Phones[1]"
"People[2].Addresses[1].Phones[2]"
```

I tried to write some code to create all possible strings automatically:

```
        var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new JsonSerializerSettings() { Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
        JObject linq = JObject.Parse(json);
        foreach (var x in linq) // DOES NOT WORK FOR CHILDREN ?????!!!!! 
        {
            string name = x.Key;
            JToken value = x.Value;
            if (value.HasValues) // Array
            {                   
                var counter = 0;
                foreach (var item in value.Values())
                {
                    dic.Add(name + $"[{counter}]", item.ToString());
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            else // String
            {
                var v = value.ToString();
                dic.Add(name, v);
            }
        }
```

However, I don't know how I can write it for all children. Any help?

Comment: Why would you create a routine to create LINQ queries? Use LINQ methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SelectTokens("..*")`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to recursively descent the JSON token hierarchy, where `".."` is the [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) *recursive descent operator* and `"*"` is a wildcard matching anything.  Then you can use [`JToken.Path`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_Path.htm) as your dictionary key:

```
var dic = linq.SelectTokens("..*")
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Path, t => t.ToString());
```

Note this includes the root token.  If you want to skip it, do:

```
var dic = linq.SelectTokens("..*")
    .Where(t => t != linq)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Path, t => t.ToString());
```

You could also use [`JContainer.DescendantsAndSelf()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_DescendantsAndSelf.htm)  or [`JContainer.Descendants()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JContainer_Descendants.htm) to do the recursive descent, filtering out all `JProperty` nodes for the same result:

```
var dic = linq.Descendants()
    .Where(t => t.Type != JTokenType.Property)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Path, t => t.ToString());
```

Comment: Adding `.Where (j => !j.Children().Any())` to your first query gives the exact result required. Great answer.