# How do I get a list of all properties in a JSON document?

Tags: recursion, json.net

I have a dynamic JSON document but for the sake of this question, imagine it resembles the following:

`{
  "name": "Jungle Gym",
  "age": 25,
  "favorite_color": "#ffa500",
  "gender": "male",
  "location": {
    "city": "Seattle",
    "state": "WA",
    "citystate": "Seattle, WA"
  },
  "pets": [
    {
      "type": "dog",
      "name": "Foo",
      "food": [
          "chicken",
          "beef",
          "fish"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "cat",
      "name": "Bar"
    }
  ]
}`

How do I get a list of all property names in the document? I can get the top level property names ("name", "age", "favorite_color", "gender", "location", "pets") but I need to get all property names down to "location.state" or "pets.food" and, if the properties / objects exist, even deeper.
I started using the following:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(json);

foreach (JProperty property in model.Properties())
{
    if (property.Value.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        foreach (var tmp in property.Children())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tmp.SelectToken().);
        }
    }
}
```

but cannot seem to navigate into the objects beyond the top level to get the next level of properties (location properties, e.g.). Ideally, I'd like the list of derived property names to include the full path to the property, e.g., `location.city`, `location.state`, etc., instead of just the property name, e.g. `city`, `state`.

How can I get a list of all properties in a JSON document with potentially various levels of nesting?

Comment: Something like this maybe?  [How can I generate all possible LINQ strings of a json object for Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38463735/3744182).  You may need to filter out properties whose values are not themselves containers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get all the keys in Json string (all levels), you could use `Descendants` and `Path` properties to fetch the details.

```
var data = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
var result = data.Descendants()
            .OfType<JProperty>()
            .Select(f=>Regex.Replace(f.Path,@"\[[0-9]\]",string.Empty))
            .Distinct();
```

Please note the Regex is used to replace all the indices that might result due to pets list.

Output,

[image]